# Google sheet -> filtering a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I created the following sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AJmzlBlrDZ0mfb_9aSm83fzZxrwYWOxWGxjNhlfqPLA/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

I am trying to find a formula to calculate the totals (C7, C8, C9) and wherever it is copied ie C17, C18, C19)

So for C7 I want to sum column D (Duration) wherever:

- the Date (col A) is the same as the total row date (that is A7)
- The Category (col E) is Internal

Similarly for So for C8 I want to sum column D (Duration) wherever:

- the Date (col A) is the same as the total row date (that is A8)
- The Category (col E) is External

and

for C9 I want to sum column D (Duration) wherever:

- the Date (col A) is the same as the total row date (that is A9)
- Has any category

I tried for C7 -

```
=QUERY({A:E, arrayformula(N(D:D))}, "select sum(Col6) where Col5='Internal' and Col1 = " & A7 & " label sum(Col6) ''",1)
```

but I get NA ??? any help ?
 -

Comment: edited my answer with my attempt

Comment: how is this a duplicate ? got nothing to do with another sheet

Comment: Do you need to use `QUERY()` or are you open to other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't complicate life with a `QUERY()` here. Instead, just use `FILTER()`.

Total Internal: `=SUM(FILTER(D:D, A:A=A7, E:E="Internal"))`

Total External: `=SUM(FILTER(D:D, A:A=A8, E:E="External"))`

Total All: `=SUM(FILTER(D:D, A:A=A9))`

Comment: just when I got it to also work with this super ugly query: =QUERY({A:E, arrayformula(N(D:D))}, "select sum(Col6) where Col5='Internal' and Col1 = date '"  & text( A18 ,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' label sum(Col6) ''",1) !! thank you